# Basic probability questions (game of heads or tails)

Tags: probability

I had my first probability course last week and I have a problem sheet to solve. Now probability is not very intuitive to me and so far I have not material to solve the following problems so my answers are essentially based on instinct:

We throw a biased coin: $P(heads) = p$. On the $n^{th}$ throw, what is the probability that:

- (1): heads appears for the first time
- (2): The number of heads is equal to the number of faces
- (3): heads has appeared **exactly** twice
- (4): heads has appeared at least twice

Here are my answers:

(1): probability = $(1-p)^{n-1}p$. Indeed, heads appeared once, hence $p^1$ and tails (which has a probability of $1-p$- appeared $n-1$ times.

(2): probability = $p^{n/2}(1-p)^{n/2}$ indeed, heads (which has a probability of p) appeared n/2 times and tails (which has a probability of $1-p$- appeared $n/2$ times.

(3): probability = $(1-p)^{n-2}p^2$ (same reasons as above)

(4): probability = $1-(1-p)^{n-1}$

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget - the order of heads/tails doesn't matter if all we're doing is counting how many times they show up.

- (1) Correct.
- (2) We should have:
  $$
  \begin{cases}
  \binom{n}{n/2}p^{n/2}(1 - p)^{n/2} &\text{if $n$ is even} \\
  0 &\text{if $n$ is odd}
  \end{cases}
  $$
- (3) We should have:
  $$
  \binom{n}{2}p^{2}(1 - p)^{n-2}
  $$
- (4) We should have:
  $$
  1 - \binom{n}{0}p^{0}(1 - p)^{n-0} - \binom{n}{1}p^{1}(1 - p)^{n-1}
  $$

Answer (score 0):

1: Looks correct. You're looking for a very specific sequence of events: n-1 times heads, and 1 times tails, so simply multiply the probabilities for those. (Assuming independence.)

2: Probably missing something. Order doesn't matter here, but your formula is for a specific order, so you are probably missing a $/2n!$

3: Similar to before, but again missing the divider to make it order-independent. You are probably missing a $/(2! * (n-2)!)$

4: Similar to 3, but add up with the results for heads exactly once or 0 times. You probably received cumulative probability tables for that.